# Select all rows but only specific columns

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Whats the linq+lambada expression to select all records in a table but only specific columns.

I tried something like the following which didnt work:

```
 var Dc = new MyDataContext();
 var mydata = Dc.TableA;
 var newdata = mydata.Select(d => d  (new {d.columnA,d.columnB,d.columnC}));
```

Comment: In what manner did it "not work"?

Answer (score 2):

You were close - you have to project to an anonymous types with the columns you want:

```
var mydata = Dc.TableA.Select(d => new {d.columnA,d.columnB,d.columnC});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you've got is a minor error in your code (in the example at least)

```
var Dc = new MyDataContext();
var mydata = Dc.TableA;
var newdata = mydata.Select(d => new {d.columnA,d.columnB,d.columnC});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Dc = new MyDataContext();

var newdata = Dc.TableA.Select(d => new {d.columnA,d.columnB,d.columnC});
```